Plotly generated pie chart text exceed page boundary
I am using plotly to generate a pie chart, with textinfo set in outside of the sector. However, when number of sectors increase to a large amount, the textinfo will not shown in the figure frame
A MWE is as the following
import plotly.express as px
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

allData = []

for i in range(100):
    ele = {}
    ele['Category'] = "Category_" + str(i)
    ele['number'] = i + 1
    allData.append(ele)

df = pd.DataFrame(allData)

fig = px.pie(names = df['Category'], values = df['number'], hole = 0.5)
fig.update_traces(textinfo = 'label+value', textposition = "outside")
fig.show()

It gives me something like this. Some of the text info get lost in upper and lower boundary

When I zoom out the page, all the text info shows up

But this time the font size become quite small to recognize.
Is there a way to generate a large 100% size image with scrollbars? With that all information will be visible.

Hi Eric - is it necessary for you to have a pie chart, and for the pie chart to have this many categories? You might find it useful to have another chart like a Sunburst if your data can be hierarchical or a Treemap might be helpful as well! I appreciate this doesn't help your answer but it might make it more clear what's going on to the people using the chart :)

Hi @AshOldershaw. Thank you for the suggestion. I do know Sunburst and Treemap. In my case since the category don't have hierarchy, so Sunburst/Treemap may not help a lot. I also want to dig inside the plotly technical details to customize the output.

There are three things you can do :

With textinfo='label+value', each label/value pair occupy two lines, you can save some space by showing them on the same line by specifying texttemplate instead.

By default the resolution of the plot fits the browser window, you can increase it as necessary by specifying a large layout width/height.

The font size is set according to the space available but you can still tweak it (and the font family as well, since some are more readable than others when the size is small, cf. this post).


fig = px.pie(names=df['Category'], values=df['number'], hole=0.5)

fig.update_traces(texttemplate='%{label}: %{value}', textposition="outside")

fig.update_layout(
    width=2048,
    height=2048,
    font_family='Segoe UI',
    font_size=11
)

fig.show()


Thanks for the help @ericlavault. texttemplate is awesome compared to textinfo. And set width and height do fix the problem. I am wondering is there are a way to make the image size adaptive for the whole content

Yes you could set the layout size according to the number of slices len(df['Category']). If you plan to show/hide slices via the legend and need the layout to resize according to the number of visible slices, you would need to create that behavior on the clientside by passing a post_script (ie. a javascript snippet, where you can directly use the Plotly.js API) to the show() method. If you need help on that feel free to ask a new question, I will have a look.
